# Reset html link attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following line in my html

```html
<a href="img/1.jpg" data-role="trigger" data-url="img/1.jpg">a link </a>
```

Then I'm using the chrome dev console to change the attribute `data-url` to another link. Can I in some way afterwards reset this link to its default value? I've seen a `reset()` function but I guess it doesn't work for this problem.

Comment: you'd have to store the original value somewhere.

Comment: You can add another data attribute and set the data-url back to that

Comment: The assignment is "Write a function that resets your thumbnails to their original data-url values and changes another one at random." for more context.

Comment: perhaps remove `data-role="trigger"` its looks like a hook for something which is changing it, if you want the original href then simply dont add it

Comment: why are not using an img tag?

Answer (score 0):

Store in another attribute

```js
const anc = document.getElementById("anc1");
anc.dataset.saveurl = anc.dataset.url;
anc.dataset.url="otherurl";
```

```html
<a href="img/1.jpg" id="anc1" data-role="trigger" data-url="img/1.jpg">Click</a>
```

result:

`<a href="img/1.jpg" id="anc1" data-role="trigger" data-url="otherurl" data-saveurl="img/1.jpg">Click</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Another perfect use case for [`WeakMap`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap)!

```js
const wm = new WeakMap()

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(el => {
    wm.set(el, el.dataset.url)

    delete el.dataset.url

    el.onclick = () => {
        console.log('html:', el.outerHTML, '\nweakmap:', wm.get(el))
    }
})
```

```html
<button data-url="img/1.jpg">Click</button>
<br>
<button data-url="img/2.jpg">Click</button>
<br>
<button data-url="img/3.jpg">Click</button>
```